# How can I add a click handler in Vue used in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In my Laravel application, I have made a component in Vue. The component itself is rendering properly, but the click handler is not firing. I have read many articles on the issue, but can't find the solution.(https://prnt.sc/tyiwmh + https://prnt.sc/tyiwwb + https://prnt.sc/tyix8l)

```
<template>
    <div class="item border rounded-lg p-3">
        <header>
            <h2 class="mb-3">John Doe</h2>
            <div class="arrows" v-on:click="showContent">
                <img src="storage/img/chevron-down-light.svg" alt="" class="arrow-down">
                <img src="storage/img/chevron-up-light.svg" alt="" class="arrow-up">
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="item-content" v-if="visible">
            <div class="content-1">
            <ul>
                <li><b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:john.doe@hotmail.com">john.doe@hotmail.com</a></li>
                <li><b>Tel:</b> <a href="tel:+3249998877">0497 99 88 77</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="content-2">
                <ul>
                    <li><b>Vertrekplaats:</b> Ark van Noë</li>
                    <li><b>Aankomstplaats:</b> Watermolen Grobbendonk</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="content-3">
                <ul>
                    <li>2 enkelzitkajaks</li>
                    <li>3 dubbelzitkajaks</li>
                    <li>0 canadese kano's</li>
                    <li>2 zwemvesten</li>
                    <li>3 tonnetjes</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="content-4">
                <h3>Extra info:</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt fuga dignissimos hic? Velit, ea aliquam! Consequuntur provident vitae, hic repudiandae, animi, ipsa ullam quidem accusamus vero ipsum aut porro nostrum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showContent: function() {
            console.log('the button is clicked');
        }
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: The function fires normally when clicking inside the ``div``. What's the problem?

Comment: check with the div with class "arrows", see whether there is height and width covers up the clicking area

Comment: @MajedBadawi the problem is that the click handler is not firing. I think that my data object and my methods object are undefined, but I'm wondering why...

Comment: @KurtChun you were right that the div did not have a height of itself. Therefore, I put the click listener to the images, unfortunately with the same result (https://prnt.sc/tz4c2n)

Comment: I tested it and it works. The console is printing when clicking on the ``div`` conent, i.e., the images in this case..

Comment: Is this the entire program or there are other code or styling?

Answer (score 0):

This might help no method necessary:

```
<div class="arrows" @click="visisble = !visible">
                <img @click="visisble = !visible"
                     :src="'storage/img/chevron-' + (visible ? 'down-light.svg':'up-light.svg')"
                     alt=""
                     :class="'arrow-' + (visible ? 'down' : 'up' )">
</div>
```